# MySQL select with joins and columns multiplication before row SUM

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum, multiplication

i have many tables, from where i'm doing select, but i will write only about important part.
I have 2 tables

accomodation:

```
id | title | desc | etc..
```

accomodation_rooms:

```
id | accomodation_id | beds | rooms
```

Then i have long select which works good until i want to filter, how many beds (beds * rooms) has accomodation. If i try simple select from table accomodation_rooms with multiplication, it works good. So the problem should be somewhere, where I join other tables.

This is my select:

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
  SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons 
FROM 
  (SELECT id, aid, title_en, title_url_en, address, city_id, zip, district_id, province_id, region_id, country_id, mountain_id, stars, latitude, longitude, picture, valid_from, valid_to 
  FROM accomodation 
  ORDER BY info_date_add DESC) 
    AS accomodation 
LEFT JOIN db_cities 
  ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
  ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
      < '50' 
JOIN accomodation_rooms 
  ON accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id 
WHERE 
  db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_title%' AND 
  accomodation.region_id = '8' 
GROUP BY 
  accomodation.aid 
HAVING 
  total_persons >= '1' 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN 
    accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND 
    accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN 
    NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND 
    accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 
    END, 
  accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

total_persons should return 13 
but it returns 624, but i really don't understan why?

Comment: One of your joined tables is resulting in multiple rows (at a guess skireshort_locations), hence you land up with multiple rows on the result set before the GROUP BY (ie, a bedroom appears more than once). Hence when you SUM them up they are counted multiple times (48 times in this case).

Comment: Yes you are right, table skiresort_locations has 5 rows in this case. When i remove JOIN to skiresort_locations table, total_personal still isn't right... What can i do? Shoul i use some GROUP BY or to do some other JOIN for skiresort_locations? Because there is problem that i can join skiresort_locations with accomodation only by their distance (latitude, longitude)...

Comment: Note that in the absence of any user variables, ORDER BY clauses in subqueries are redundant. Any pretence otherwisem is dicing with disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Think the quantity you want is probably best obtain by using a subselect.

I assume that accomodation_rooms is a table that stores multiple rows for some accomodation saying how many of each number of beds that location has (ie, 1 by 5 bed room, 2 by 3 bed, 5 by 2 bed).

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
  accomodation_rooms.total_persons 
FROM 
  (SELECT id, aid, title_en, title_url_en, address, city_id, zip, district_id, province_id, region_id, country_id, mountain_id, stars, latitude, longitude, picture, valid_from, valid_to 
  FROM accomodation 
  ORDER BY info_date_add DESC) 
    AS accomodation 
LEFT JOIN db_cities 
  ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
  ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
      < '50' 
INNER JOIN (SELECT accomodation_id, SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons FROM accomodation_rooms GROUP BY accomodation_id) accomodation_rooms
  ON accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id 
  AND accomodation_rooms.total_persons >= 1
WHERE db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_title%' 
AND accomodation.region_id = '8' 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 
    END, 
  accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

As a minor point, not sure you need the original select on accomodation as a sub select (or has an order by clause, but you don't appear to have a limit within it so I don't think it will have any effect):-

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.id, 
  accomodation.aid, 
  accomodation.title_en, 
  accomodation.title_url_en, 
  accomodation.address, 
  accomodation.city_id, 
  accomodation.zip, 
  accomodation.district_id, 
  accomodation.province_id, 
  accomodation.region_id, 
  accomodation.country_id, 
  accomodation.mountain_id, 
  accomodation.stars, 
  accomodation.latitude, 
  accomodation.longitude, 
  accomodation.picture, 
  accomodation.valid_from, 
  accomodation.valid_to, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
  accomodation_rooms.total_persons 
FROM accomodation
LEFT JOIN db_cities 
  ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
  ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
      < '50' 
INNER JOIN (SELECT accomodation_id, SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons FROM accomodation_rooms GROUP BY accomodation_id) accomodation_rooms
  ON accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id 
  AND accomodation_rooms.total_persons >= 1
WHERE db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_title%' 
AND accomodation.region_id = '8' 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 
    END, 
  accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

EDIT - Modified to get the latest accommodation record for each aid and join that back to get the rest of the latest accommodation record.

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
  accomodation_rooms.total_persons 
FROM (SELECT aid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM accomodation GROUP BY aid) accomodation_max
INNER JOIN accomodation ON accomodation_max.aid = accomodation.aid AND accomodation_max.max_info_date_add = accomodation.info_date_add
LEFT JOIN db_cities ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
      < '50' 
INNER JOIN (SELECT accomodation_id, SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons FROM accomodation_rooms GROUP BY accomodation_id) accomodation_rooms
ON accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id AND accomodation_rooms.total_persons >= 1
WHERE db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_title%' 
AND accomodation.region_id = '8' 
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 
    END, 
  accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

EDIT - adding a MIN for the distance with a GROUP BY clause. However not sure that this will be much faster than using DISTINCT. It is forcing a LOT of calculations on the JOIN (ie, if you have 100 records on accommodation and 100 records on skiresort_locations then that is going to result in 10000 reasonable complex calculations to determine the distances. If you can narrow down skiresort_locations prior to the calculation then this would save a fairly bit of time (for example, denormalising a bit but maybe you have a region table that joins to accomodation on region_id, and it might contain the min and max latitude and longitude for that region, which you could use for the join, then put the complex calculation into the WHERE clause instead). Also you have a LIKE clause for the db_counties.title_url_en that has a leading wildcard and this will be slow as it won't use an index (although it should be using the country_id index on the join).

```
SELECT 
  accomodation.*, 
  db_cities.title_en AS city, 
  db_cities.title_url AS city_url, 
  db_countries.title_url_en AS country_url, 
  accomodation_rooms.total_persons,
  MIN(((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)
FROM (SELECT aid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM accomodation GROUP BY aid) accomodation_max
INNER JOIN accomodation ON accomodation_max.aid = accomodation.aid AND accomodation_max.max_info_date_add = accomodation.info_date_add
LEFT JOIN db_cities ON db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
JOIN skiresort_locations 
  ON 
    (((acos(sin((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + 
    cos((skiresort_locations.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * 
    cos(((skiresort_locations.longitude - 
    accomodation.longitude)*
    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) 
      < '50' 
INNER JOIN (SELECT accomodation_id, SUM(accomodation_rooms.beds * accomodation_rooms.rooms) AS total_persons FROM accomodation_rooms GROUP BY accomodation_id) accomodation_rooms
ON accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id = accomodation.id AND accomodation_rooms.total_persons >= 1
WHERE db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country_title%' 
AND accomodation.region_id = '8' 
GROUP BY accomodation.id, 
  db_cities.title_en, 
  db_cities.title_url, 
  db_countries.title_url, 
  accomodation_rooms.total_persons
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() 
      THEN 0 
  WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' 
      THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 
    END, 
  accomodation.title_en 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Great it works but one more small problem :)
You asked me, why i use subselect on accomodation. It's because "backup" - everytime you edit row in accomodation, it insert new one. In subselect, you can notice 'ORDER BY info_date_add' and at the end, there 'GROUP BY accomodation.aid' 
aid is accomdoation identificator that is uniqe for eeach accomodation (not for each row).
I used your code, it works but only until i edited one row in accomodation (it's new row now). I noticed one thing.

Comment: When i add to first select 'accomodation_rooms.accomodation_id AS aaa' and then i echo aaa it use optional accomodation_id from accomodation_rooms. I need it will use last inserted ID from accomodation table.
I noticed this when i removed one type of room (3x2). Then it showed 7 available beds but when i try to find accomodation with 10 available beds, it showed 13 available beds (this was in older version that is still stored in DB)

Comment: OK, will have a fiddle. The existing way of doing it using a GROUP BY to get rid of the non latest accommodation record is not safe

Comment: why it's not safe? What you can suggest?

Comment: I have added a new suggestion. Problem is that you were doing a group by aid, but the columns it brings back for the non aggregate fields from accommodation might come from any of the rows with that aid. For example, the picture could change 3 times for an accommodation record. Your GROUP BY would mean it would only bring back one of the resulting accommodation rows, but which one is not defined, and using the sort in the sub select is not certain to define it.

Comment: ouch early joy... now it's not grouping in right way, i have 6 same results :(

Comment: but there is this problem only when select contains 'JOIN skiresort_locations'

Comment: Think this is because of the JOIN on skiresort_locations. You could fix this a few ways. Given that you don't return anything from skiresort_locations the easiest is to probably just do a SELECT DISTINCT. Alternatively add a field from skiresort_locations to the SELECT and use MIN (possibly the best solution if you want to know the nearest location. You could also move it from a JOIN onto skiresort_locations into a subselect and use IN, but as you are using details from accommodation to calculate the distance this would need to be a correlated sub select and so likely perform badly.

Comment: Sorry i feel like idiot but can you show me, how can i use MIN(distance) in SELECT? When i use SELECT DISTINCT it works good. But now it's really slow (2,5s to get results - when there is JOIN to skiresort_locations), without it it's about 0,6s

Comment: I don't understand one thing... Sometimes my select is short (dependes on selected filters). When it is without skiresort_locations, time of select is about 20 seconds! But when the select is longer witd locations etc, it's about 2 seconds :(

Comment: it looks like since i have 'FROM (SELECT aid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM accomodation GROUP BY aid) accomodation_max INNER JOIN accomodation ON accomodation_max.aid = accomodation.aid AND accomodation_max.max_info_date_add = accomodation.info_date_add' instead of my subselect it's really slow on short select...

Comment: The sub select as it was would often give give the wrong result so not an option. Beyond that does accommodation have an index to cover both aid and info_date_added. Afraid I would need more details of the tables (both structures and the data) to have a serious play to tune it more.

Answer (score 1):

Further reply for the new requirement.

You need to join back from the  found accomodation to the cities table again to get the city details for that accomodation:-

```
SELECT 
   accomodation.id, 
   accomodation.aid,
   accomodation.title_$lang, 
   accomodation.title_url_$lang,
   accomodation.address,
   accomodation.zip, 
   accomodation.stars, 
   accomodation.picture, 
   accomodation.valid_from, 
   accomodation.valid_to, 
   de_cities_accomodation.title_$lang AS city,
   de_cities_accomodation.title_url AS city_url, 
   db_countries.title_url_$lang AS country_url
FROM  db_cities 
INNER JOIN accomodation 
   ON 
   ( 
      db_cities.id = accomodation.city_id 
      OR 
      (((acos(sin((db_cities.latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) + cos((db_cities.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((accomodation.latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((db_cities.longitude - accomodation.longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) < '20' ) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT aid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM accomodation GROUP BY aid) accomodation_max 
   ON 
      accomodation_max.aid = accomodation.aid AND 
      accomodation_max.max_info_date_add = accomodation.info_date_add 
LEFT JOIN db_cities de_cities_accomodation
   ON de_cities_accomodation.id = accomodation.city_id 
JOIN db_countries 
   ON db_countries.id = accomodation.country_id 
WHERE 
   db_countries.title_url_en LIKE '%country%' AND 
   db_cities.title_url LIKE '%city%' AND 
   db_cities.id = '1258' 
GROUP BY accomodation.aid 
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() THEN 0 
     WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' THEN 1 
   ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: It should have made a difference as the city is now coming from a different source.

Comment: it's really the same... i don't understand why

Comment: Afraid I can see nothing wrong. I would need some test data to recreate the problem.

Comment: I have one more question to you... I joined one more table accomodation_price ON accomodation_price.accomodation_aid = accomodation.aid and then I ORDER BY MIN(accomodation_price.price) but there is problem, that first results are that, which doesn't have any value in table accomodation_prize. I want to order it by:
1. with price from lowest.
2. without price.

I tried to add condition to CASE... WHEN MIN(accomodation_price.price) > '0' but nothing happened. I also tried to use condition IS NOT NULL but also nothing...

Comment: I would try _ORDER BY CASE WHEN accomodation_price.price IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, accomodation_price.price_ . I.E., order by a marker as to whether the price is null, then by the price within that.

Comment: And it is ok that my type for PRICE is FLOAT?